# Passing arguments to plt.savefig in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wrote a function to save plots in Matplotlib. When I wanted to use it by calling `plt.savefig(fname=path, dpi=dpi, format=ext, bbox_inches="tight")` I got the following error.

```
  File "/home/jruota/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 697, in savefig
    res = fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jruota/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1572, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: print_figure() takes at least 2 arguments (5 given)
```

This error does not occur when I change the call to `plt.savefig(path, dpi=dpi, format=ext, bbox_inches="tight")`. My guess is this error has something to do with the `*` and `**` argument packing and unpacking but I am unsure how exactly. Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: file name is always required argument for `savefig` therefore `savefig` does not have keyword argument `fname`. `fname` is just a variable like yours `path`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, it's clear that if

```
plt.savefig(path, dpi=dpi, format=ext, bbox_inches="tight")
```

is working fine, you may simply use it.

The error comes from `fname` not being a named argument. [The documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=matplotlib%20pyplot%20savefig#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig) may be a bit confusing for people not familiar with call signatures in python at this point.

The signature is `matplotlib.pyplot.savefig(*args, **kwargs)`, where an argument `fname` needs to be set and further keyword arguments can be specified. The argument must not be a keyword argument of course. So in

```
fname = "myfile.png"
plt.savefig(fname, dpi=100)
```

`fname` is the argument, while in

```
fname = "myfile.png"
plt.savefig(fname=fname, dpi=100)
```

`fname` is a keyword argument, such that no argument specifying the filename is found.

You may test with a self-defined function, if you want:

```
def f(*args,**kwargs):
    print "args: ",  args
    print "kwargs: ", kwargs
```

Then

```
f("q", k="W")  # prints args:  ('q',)
               #        kwargs:  {'k': 'W'}
```

while

```
f(fname="q", k="W") # prints args:  ()
                    #        kwargs:  {'k': 'W', 'fname': 'q'}
```

In the latter case `args` is empty.

Comment: Besides the implementation, do you know the reason `fname` should only be called as a positional and not as a keyword?

Comment: The reason is purely the implementation of the `savefig` function. One could have implemented it differently of course - that was the choice of the programmer. However it somehow makes sense: You often want required arguments to be positional ones (calling `savefig` without the file(name) would not make sense) and optional arguments to be keyword arguments.